# How to mark drive as SSD in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, drivers

I have 2 SSDs in RAID-0 which is visible to Windows 7 Home Premium as one drive, which, I think, it does not detect as SSD because I don't see any sign of it - it detects it as "TOSHIBA RAID LD0 SCSI Disk Device".

How can I manually direct Windows 7 that this drive is SSD ?

Comment: What is the question behind the question? Why do you want Windows 7 to recognize them as SSD? Worrying about TRIM, or?

Comment: Yes, I worry that it will die without TRIM.

Comment: It won't die, just its speed will degrade without TRIM. Intel say it is about 10%, real world benchmarks show around 40%. 
I don't know about a RAID controller that would support `TRIM` _when_ the drives are in a RAID configuration. However some RAID controller support TRIM if the drives are just simply connected to the RAID controller without any RAID setup.
If you have some onboard RAID chip (which is usually called _fake-raid_) then you surely won't have any TRIM support either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, the RAID system provides logical volume(s), not individual drives, to the OS. That's one of the points of using RAID, storage virtualization.

Answer (score 3):

The two drives in RAID 0 are not an SSD. They're two drives in RAID 0, and that's what they're detected as.